# The scene change script for my unity project is not working, I cant understand why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code for the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class changescene : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this with a 3D cube tagged player is not changing scenes and neither showing any errors.

Comment: Does "Player" have a rigidbody? Does "Player" have a collider?   Is the changescene collider set to IsTrigger?  Is the collider on the same object as the script?  Thats a good list to start with.  [Docs for OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) is the first place I would check.

Comment: Debug.Log every step to see where the issue is. Is it entering the OnTriggerenter function? Is it entering the CompareTag if statement? Is it entering  the input if statement when you press space? This is basic debugging and there should be no need to go on SO with such issue at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetKeyDown` is only `true` **once** per key press and only during a single frame where the key went down.

It is extremely unlikely that you press the key down exactly in the `FixedUpdate` physics all when the trigger enters your collider!

You want to split your physics / collision detection from user input and rather do e.g.

```
public class changescene : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isEntered;

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

        isEntered = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        
        isEntered = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(isEntered && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want to make it a bit more efficient without an `Update` method that runs most of time unnecessary you can use a Coroutine like e.g.

```
public class changescene : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;

        StartCoroutine(CheckSpaceRoutine());
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckSpaceRoutine()
    {
        while(true) 
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
                yield break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```